# How to remove a string date exist in a list of Strings in dart?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, datetime, date-format

I have a list of strings and one if it's items looks like this  '19-06-2022 12:37' ..

How can i remove any pattern like this if it exist in the list using Dart language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove any pattern from string by using String class method `replaceAll`. If you want to remove any pattern then you need to use RegExp like below example.

There are also other method like `replaceFirst`, `replaceRange` for more details [Read Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String-class.html)

```
 String testSt = "12-02-2022 16:23";

 String myPattern = "^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2}) [012]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-6][0-9]";

 testSt.replaceAll(new RegExp(myPattern),"");
```

Comment: I know that i can replace any string i want, but the problem is i can't replace this date as a static date because date is changing, so the basic idea is i just need to define a pattern that if it's found then remove it

Comment: then you need to use RegExp like print(s.replaceAll(new RegExp('your pattren'),''));

Comment: Do you know what is the pattern for this '19-06-2022 12:37' ?

Comment: that may help you -  ^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01]))\-([0]{0,1}[1-9]|1[012])\-\d\d\d\d\s([0-1]?[0-9]|2?[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$

Comment: Thank you, the pattern worked, please update your answer as using a regular expression

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
   List<String> stringList = ["20-11-2022 12:37", "19-06-2022 12:37", "19-03-2022 12:37", "09-06-2022 12:37", "x", "y", "z","w"];
   stringList = stringList.where((element) => !element.contains("-")).toList();
```

Comment: No need to build a .where by hand.  Use .where.